# bootstrap 4 collapse not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any type of collapse I use is just not working. I have re-downloaded all the files and I have my scripts  in the correct order. Jquery first (this seems to be the piece most with similar questions are missing)
At this point I am working with just an empty file and am trying all the demo code off Bootstrap's site and I am still at a lost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" contents="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Please Work</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-inverse p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>


    <!--- scripts  -->
    <script scr="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="js/tether.js"></script>
    <script scr="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working for me: https://codepen.io/sidhuko/pen/YxGywy. Which build of v4 are you using? alpha.v6?

Comment: Yes, I am using the newest V4.6. It works if I use the CDNs. The ones from the bootstrap site actually use jquery 3.1.1 and I was trying the newest 3.2.1. I wonder if that was causing the issues. (I checked my file path names like 500 times.) (-edit for spelling)

Comment: The codepen is using 3.2.1. I see it now!!! `src` is spelt `scr` on your script tags. Use a HTML validator :)